# Creating nodes on the fly for large scale deployments using Chef

Tags: chef-infra, chef-recipe, knife

As per my understanding nodes need to be created on the Chef server BEFORE running the chef-clients. In my case, nodes are auto-scaled and I cannot create nodes on the server beforehand. I don't want to run knife commands on the nodes as well.
Is there a way in Chef to handle such a situation where roles are defined on the Chef server but nodes are not?

I did see the first-boot.json method but its not well documented and there is very little information about it which makes me wonder if that is a non-standard approach.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is not a non-standart approach, it is the method used by knife bootstrap to define the runlist for the very first chef-client run on the host being bootstrapped.

So basically on your provisionning process you install chef, give it the validation key and a first-boot.json which contain its runlist.

Quoting the documentation [here](http://docs.getchef.com/essentials_nodes_bootstrap.html)

> first-boot.json is generated from the workstation as part of the initial knife bootstrap command.

I would say the best way if to use `knife bootstrap -r <runlist>` on a test machine and to inspect the first-boot.json produced to create your own after that.

an exemple of an initial json is [here](http://docs.getchef.com/install_bootstrap.html) (bottom of the doc)

Answer (score 1):

Actually the reverse is true, creating the node objects manually is often an error and not supported very well. The easiest way to do autoscaling with Chef is to bake chef-client, a client.rb, and your validation key in to the VM image. Then make a script to run chef-client when the VM starts to register itself with the Chef Server.

I use [a packer template](https://github.com/coderanger/brix/blob/master/packer/balanced-client.json) and a [cloud-init script](https://github.com/coderanger/brix/blob/master/packer/client-bootstrap.sh) for this.